# Is there a way to control my iOS app using the Apple Remote?

Tags: ios, api, infrared, remote-control

I think the title of this question is sufficient. But, just in case there are doubts about what an Apple Remote is, click [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC377LL/A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no bluetooth Apple remote.  The one you have referenced is infrared, like any other tv remote.  iOS devices (with the exception of AppleTV) do not receive IR.

Comment: You may control the iPod functions of an iPhone or iPod touch provided the iPhone is placed in a universal dock that has the IR receiver. However, there are no APIs to control a third party app using the remote. Without the dock iPhones or iPod touches won't receive IR.